# Algorithm for text classification

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning, text-processing

I have millions of short (up to 30 words) documents which I need to split into several known categories. It's possible, that a document matches several of the categories (seldom, but possible). It's also possible that a document doesn't match any of the categories (also seldom). I also have millions of documents which have already been categorized. What algorithm should I use to do the job. I don't need to do it fast. I need to be sure that the algorithm categorizes correctly (as far as possible).
What algorithm should I use? Is there an implementation of in in C#?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [term frequency and inverse document frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) also [cosine similarity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) to find important words to create categories and assign documents to categories based on similarity

EDIT:

Found an example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tfidf.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting articles :

- [A self-organizing semantic map for information retrieval](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.93.8711&rep=rep1&type=pdf)
- [WEBSOM - self-organizing maps of document collections](http://www.cis.hut.fi/tho/publications/wsom97_websom.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

The major issue IMHO here is the length of the documents. I think I would call it phrase classification and there is work going on on this because of the twitter thing. You could bring in additional text performing a web search on the 30 words and then analyzing the top matches. There is a paper about this but I can't find it right now. Then I would try a feature vector approach (tdf-idf as in Jimmy's answer) and a multiclass SVM for classification.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a decision tree combined with a NN?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SVM Algorithm for Classify text in C# with libsvm.net library.

Comment: Why the late (and less complete answer)?